XSS Vulnerability Warning
I have a website running SiteLock. Recently I've received the warning that there are a couple of XSS issues. I traced it back to a list page from a custom component that has filtering options. It's using the default form fields to render a Search field and 2 Select lists. I don't understand why it's coming up as an issue. The data is being sanitized on the backend.
This is what comes up when I click on the Description of the issue:

boxchecked,filter[search],list[audience][],list[topic],list[type],task

However, when I test it out by adding a 'script' tag, it correctly doesn't display it and I get the following error message:

Any ideas how I can fix this error message?
